# Align a table above an div

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an div container where an image is displayed, above that image I would like to show an table. So, my problem is that the table isn't displayed over the image. Instead it is shown after the image? Can somebody tell me how I can align the table above the image?

```
<div id="foto2">
    <img src="foto2.jpg" class="bg"> <span class="oben">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td onclick="playAudio('test.mp3')">Hamdullah</td>
            <td onclick="playAudio('test2.mp3')">Was?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td onclick="playAudio('test.mp3')">Penner</td>
            <td onclick="playAudio('test2.mp3')">Heidefick</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </span>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#00061c;
}
img.bg {
    width: 100%;
}
.oben {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Hallo";
    src: url(hallo.ttf);
}
table {
    width:100%;
    color:#FFF;
}
tr {
    text-align:center;
}
td {
    font-family: Hallo;
    font-size: xx-large;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see your table "above" ( I suppose you mean in the z axis.) so the image is displayed as a background of the table you can use 2 alternatives solutions

**1) a background for your foto2 div.
2) an absolute positioned table**

**Alternative 1 : Background for your foto2 div.**

[image]
I dont think you need that oben rule with a left property for a not positioned element (which  actually wont work either). The span tag as well I will keep it out of the game unless you have a very particular reason for it...mmmm

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/b74bq/)

This is the css for foto2 div. You may adjust the repeat and other properties at your will

```
#foto2 {
  background:url( your image url here );
}
```

this is the html

```
<div id="foto2"> 
 <table>
 <tr>
    <td onclick="playAudio('test.mp3')">Hamdullah</td>
    <td onclick="playAudio('test2.mp3')">Was?</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td onclick="playAudio('test.mp3')">Penner</td>
    <td onclick="playAudio('test2.mp3')">Heidefick</td>
</tr>
</table>

 </div>
```

**Alternative 2: Absolute positioned table**

With this alternative you may use a full width image and not to be constrained by the table size. its your call which alternative to use
Your foto2 div should be relative positioned.Then....

```
table { 
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
width:100%;
color:#FFF;
}
```

And here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/bvHh3/) for the absolute table

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the image after the table, like?

```
 </table>
     <img src="foto2.jpg" class="bg" />
```

Or put it in the lowest row of the table like:

```
 <tr>
    <td onclick="playAudio('test.mp3')">Penner</td>
    <td onclick="playAudio('test2.mp3')">Heidefick</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><img src="foto2.jpg" class="bg"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

By the way why are you using `<span>` and put the `<table>` inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting it after the closing span tag

```
<div id="foto2">
    <span class="oben">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="playAudio('test.mp3')">Hamdullah</td>
                <td onclick="playAudio('test2.mp3')">Was?</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="playAudio('test.mp3')">Penner</td>
                <td onclick="playAudio('test2.mp3')">Heidefick</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </span>
    <img src="foto2.jpg" class="bg" />
 </div>
```